# MSBUILD - block until a file exists on an ftp server?

Tags: msbuild, ftp

As part of a build process .. I would like to block the build until a file gets created (exists) remotely at an ftp location, after which I would continue the build. (Preferably with somekind of time out limit).

Suggestions?

Is this even possible using only the standard msbuild task and/or extensionPack/communitytask?

Comment: Curious. This sounds like a production, post build step. What's the intent?

Comment: One build step involves ftp'ing data to a destination, and having the destination perform processing on it. The remote creation of a file on the ftp server is that only way for me to know if the destination is done processing. It's definetly not a trivial/typical build.

Comment: @vicjugador- And this step is absolutely required for your source code to be translated into machine code? Or this is something you have to do to release the product? Since most shops these days focus on a fast CI environment, your request is unusual in that it runs counter to that goal.

Comment: Yep absolutely required .. the project that I'm working on is certainly unusual, and there are some steps that can't really be changed. The build script in question deals with building and performing a Data Migration project, so there's certainly some atypical usage of MSBUILD (which is also outside of my control/choosing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to build a small custom exe (you can even compile it as a build step) that polls for the file you are looking for. Then you use the PreBuild target, or a custom target in a pre-build step to verify that the file exists.

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="WaitOnFTP">
        <Exec Command="MyFTPWaiter.exe"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Other more MSBuild oriented suggestions are to remake that exe as a custom task, or even an inline task in MSBuild 4.0.

FWIW, I've encountered a similar solution done by a peer who didn't want large binaries used by integration tests in version control and he required the use of a custom downloader in the build to get the files from a SMB share. It worked well enough.

[Custom Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9883dzc.aspx)

[Inline Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd722601.aspx)

Comment: Polling for the file is a good idea but there is software you can download that will do this for you.  There are some that sync a local folder and remote site, there are some that allow you to map a FTP site to a drive letter like a network drive, and there are some that you could configure to run as a Windows Service that will do as you suggest and constantly poll for a specific remote file to appear.  Some of this is shareware and some is supported commercial stuff.  Might want a program with a Help file if somebody other than you will be responsible for supporting it in the future.

Comment: @AlexPace - Sure. I wouldn't install any of that on my build server, especially if its a 20 minute job to write one that I can put into version control.

Comment: Yeah .. I was hoping that there would be a solution that didn't involve writing extra code .. Looks like this is the only way to do it.

Comment: @vicjugador - It's pretty simple. If you want, we can screen share and pair something out sometime this week.

Comment: Thanks for the offer .. I agree with you it's pretty simple .. I have a pet peeve against custom exe's such as these (though it seems like I'll have to write one anyway .. I was just thinking of using Java and the built in libaries) .. Most of our team doesn't have VisualStudio, so I don't want to inconvience them if they ever need to make changes